# "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to double"

Tags: java, android

I am quite new to Android / java development. I have a problem (probaly very basic) that I could not solve even after trying several workarounds and internet researches...

```
public double P_N_comp[][] = new double[16][40];
```

I populate the 16*40 values by using a function

Then I want to display the very last value of my array :

```
Double last_P_N = P_N[15][39]; // This is the line where i get the error
TextView myTextView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytextview3);
myTextView3.setText("Last P_N value" + last_P_N);
```

The error says "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to double"

So if I understand, Java wants to have an array on both sides of the expression (line with error).
But why ?
As far as I understand P_N[15][39] refers to the last value of the array which is a double (and thus, is not an array). And last_P_N has just been declared as a double....

Thank you in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
  Double last_P_N = P_N[15][39];
```

What's the P_N? The name of your array is P_N_comp.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't mix anything there?

I see your array is declared:

```
double P_N_comp[][] = new double[16][40];
```

But you are trying to assing:

```
Double last_P_N = P_N[15][39];
```

I believe there's a typo. = **P_N_comp**[15][39] should be assigned instead, not **P_N**[15][39]